# Android enable Tabs on button press in TabHost

Tags: android, tabs

im using a Tabhost with 3 Tabs. Only the first one is enabled. So when you start the activity u see the first tab fragment. when pressing on a list there or lets take a button for this example i want to set the next tab from the tabhost to enable. How can i get the Tabhost ? 
the only way I could think of is a Broastcast but it feels like a dirty way of doing this.

Here is my Parrent class with tabhost:

```
public class Tourenuebersicht_fragment extends Fragment {


private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_touren_uebersicht_fragment,
            container, false);


    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.tourenrealtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.routes)),
            Routen_fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.stops)),
            Tourstop_fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.tasks)),
            TourstopAuftrag_fragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(false);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(false);

    return mTabHost;

  }
```

and this is my first child tab:

```
public class Routen_fragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_routen_fragment,
            container, false);

    return rootView;
  }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     ListView touren = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tourenListe);
     touren.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {



            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_tour_details);
            dialog.setTitle("Tour Details");
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

    });


     touren.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```

i want to enable the next tab when Longclicking on the list.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
TabHost th = (TabHost) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

As you're using `Fragment`s, you cannot directly call `findViewById()` so you have to do it on the root `View`, obtained with `getView()`.

To change the current tab to a specific one, you can use something like this:

```
th.setCurrentTab(th.getTabWidget().getChildCount() - 1);
```

This, for instance, would activate the last tab from your tabhost.

Comment: Hmm thanks for you fast answer. I've put your line into my onActivitycreated but I get a nullpointer exception when calling  th.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setEnabled(true); as he cant find the tabhost.

Comment: Try by `getChildTabViewAt(1)` instead of `getChildAt(1)`. TabHost might be very tricky with some names...

Comment: Ok i solved it. first problem was that im using FragmentTabHost and second was that i have to use getParentFragment().getView(). But thanks alot you helped me very much :)